# How can I use react-testing-library to test that a file input shows a preview once a file is selected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

I'm struggling to test a file input component I've made to work with `react-hook-form`.

I'm following the [guidance given in the react-testing-library docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/utility/#upload).

Here's the component:

```js
// FileField.tsx

import { ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES } from "@/config"
import Image from "next/image"
import { ChangeEvent, HTMLProps, useState } from "react"
import { useFormContext } from "react-hook-form"

interface Props extends HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement> {
  name: string
}

const FileField = ({ name, ...props }: Props) => {
  const [previewUrl, setPreviewUrl] = useState<string>("")

  const { register } = useFormContext()

  const handleUploadedFile = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const file = e.target?.files?.[0]
    if (file) setPreviewUrl(URL.createObjectURL(file))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label className="ds_label" htmlFor="file">
        File
      </label>

      <input
        type="file"
        id="file"
        accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png"
        {...register(name)}
        onChange={handleUploadedFile}
        data-testid="file-input"
        {...props}
      />

      {previewUrl && <Image width={500} height={500} src={previewUrl} alt="" />} // this is what we're trying to test
    </div>
  )
}

export default FileField
```

The component works fine in the browser, but I'm  having trouble simulating the act of choosing a file, which should trigger a `previewUrl` to be set and an `<Image/>` component to be rendered.

Here's a test that shows the issue:

```js
// FileField.test.tsx

import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"
import { useForm, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form"
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event"
import FileField from "./FileField"

interface FakeFormProps {
  children: React.ReactElement
}

const FakeForm = ({ children }: FakeFormProps) => {
  const helpers = useForm()

  return <FormProvider {...helpers}>{children}</FormProvider>
}

describe("FileField", () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup()

  it("shows a preview once a file is selected", async () => {
    render(
      <FakeForm>
        <FileField name="bar" />
      </FakeForm>
    )

    await user.upload(
      screen.getByTestId("file-input"),
      new File(["blob"], "hello.png", { type: "image/png" })
    )  // problem seems to be here—this doesn't trigger the same behaviour seen in the browser

    expect(screen.getByRole("img")) // always fails :(
  })
})
```

I've already tried:

- various combos of `act`, `waitFor` and `setTimeout` to make sure there's no async weirdness going on
- swapping out `userEvent` for the simpler `fireEvent`
- a few different ways of creating the fake file to upload

My hypothesis is that the `user.upload` operation is somehow not doing all the same things that a real user selecting a file would. Eg. not triggering the `onChange` handler attached to the field, but I'm at a loss for what else to try.

Again—the component works fine, so I'd like to limit any changes to just the tests.

Comment: I’d try removing the white space from your comma delimited `accept` attribute.

Comment: My guess would be this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/32325/. If the default is to only load the `<img>` tag when it's visible, it would never actually trigger by itself with Jest, since JSDOM is only a browser emulation (no paint) and it probably wouldn't be able to simulate that behaviour since its dependent on layout. The thread has ideas, like the `priority` prop. I'll add you can easily debug if your original theory is true or not by logging the `previewUrl` in the component and checking its output in test execution (remember there will be many logs for each render).

Comment: BTW, this kind of test problem caused ultimately by JSDOM is really common. It's why a lot of people consider Cypress Component Testing or playwright component testing instead of Jest. So much easier to debug as well. And cypress-testing-library exists!